# Why my SQL is not executed?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I do not understand why `mysql_query($update)` is not executed here. All code seems fine for me, var_dump'ing elements results expected values. `echo $passed_title;` Is executing without warnings from previous line which as said is not executed (DB is not updated). Why?

```
$ask_if_empty = "SELECT id FROM content WHERE id='{$passed_id}'";
$ask_if_empty2 = mysql_query($ask_if_empty) or die($error[25]);

if (mysql_num_rows($ask_if_empty2) !== 0) 
{
    $update = "UPDATE content SET title='{$passed_title}' WHERE id='{passed_id}'";
    mysql_query($update) or die($error[25]);
    echo $passed_title;
}
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Comment: ur missing a `$` for your variable `passed_id`

Comment: "All code seems fine for me, var_dump'ing elements results expected values" - really? `echo $update`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a `$`:

```
$update = "UPDATE content SET title='{$passed_title}' WHERE id='{$passed_id}'";
```

I strongly recommend escaping strings before using them in sql queries. You can do this with `mysql_real_escape_string`. Otherwise you are open to sql injection attacks:

```
$passed_title = mysql_real_escape_string($passed_title);
```

If `$passed_id` is an integer you should prevent malicious input by using `intval()`:

```
$passed_id = intval($passed_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` column is an INTEGER, you might need to drop the single quotes around the value `id='{$passed_id}'`.

Comment: (if the OP's typo was only a typo for this question) good point!

Comment: bad point, quotes are allowed.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said *might*. In postgresql they're not, didn't know if the same applied to mysql.